# Grabbing the output of Windows Message Box to a String

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

I have searched the webs for a solution to my problem with no avail. I need to assign the message box output of a specific command to a variable. The command is `mstsc.exe /l`. For a background this command lists the IDs of the screens available for a RDP session to a windows message box. I would like to capture this output to a string of sorts so that I can parse it to grab the IDs of the displays.

The `mstsc /l` output should look something like this and be assigned to a variable:

```
0:1920 x 1080; (0,0, xxxx, yyyy),

1:1920 x 1080; (0,0, xxxx, yyyy),

2:1920 x 1080; (0,0, xxxx, yyyy)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know, you can just `ctrl` + `c` any message box (as long as it's not Delphi or Java, and it'll copy the text to the clipboard? OK you get the title and buttons too, but you can scrub those.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, but I am trying to do this as part of a powershell script so unless this is done automatically it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way to directly capture `mstsc -l` box but you could alternatively use powershell with a little research to leverage the required values programatically directly from .net

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Array = ([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens|sort -Property {$_.Displayname} )

($Array[0].DeviceName).Split('\\')[-1]
$Array[0].Bounds.Width
$Array[0].Bounds.Height
$Array[0].Bounds.Left
$Array[0].Bounds.Top
($Array[0].Bounds.Right)-1
($Array[0].Bounds.Bottom)-1

($Array[1].DeviceName).Split('\\')[-1]
$Array[1].Bounds.Width
$Array[1].Bounds.Height
$Array[1].Bounds.Left
$Array[1].Bounds.Top
($Array[1].Bounds.Right)-1
($Array[1].Bounds.Bottom)-1

($Array[2].DeviceName).Split('\\')[-1]
$Array[2].Bounds.Width
$Array[2].Bounds.Height
$Array[2].Bounds.Left
$Array[2].Bounds.Top
($Array[2].Bounds.Right)-1
($Array[2].Bounds.Bottom)-1
```

Edit: unfortunately I dont have a system displaying numbers outside of the 1, 2 or 3 to test but you could add .DeviceName to the output to show what display number is in the array, as a reference this should match except the MSTSC /l info is indexed from 0. If it doesnt then I think it is possible that it is not currently available via .net

Comment: This helped! Thank you!

Comment: This only works if mstsc /l enumerates displays 0-3.  For situations like mine, I have mstsc /l showing 0,14,15.  Is there a way to get the enumerated values like mstsc provides?

Comment: what does Start > Settings > System > Display > Advanced Display setting return. is this different

Answer (score 3):

This example uses [Microsoft UI Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'UIAutomationClient'

#Start mstsc.exe with the argument /l, retain a process reference in $mstscProc
$mstscProc = Start-Process -FilePath 'mstsc.exe' -ArgumentList '/l' -PassThru
try {
  $handle = $null
  #MainWindowHandle sometimes returns 0, this while loop is a workaround
  while ((-not $mstscProc.HasExited) -and ($null -eq $handle))
  {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    $mstscProc.Refresh()
    if ($mstscProc.MainWindowHandle -ne 0)
    {
      $handle = $mstscProc.MainWindowHandle
    }
  }

  $cTrue = [System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition]::TrueCondition
  #Get the root element of the mstsc.exe process by handle
  $root = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::FromHandle($handle)

  $rawText = $root.FindAll("Children", $cTrue) | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Current | 
    # I used inspect.exe from the WinSDK to determine the AutomationId for the element containing the text
    Where-Object AutomationId -ieq 'ContentText' | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name  
}
finally {
  $mstscProc | Stop-Process -Force  
}

#split the raw text an process one line at a time
$rawText -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
  $parts = @()
  try {
    #Convert the line format "0: 1920 x 1080; (0, 0, 1919, 1079)" into numbers seperated by , then split
    $parts = @($_.replace(':', ',').replace(' x ', ',').replace(';', ',').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(' ', '').Trim() -split ',')    
  }
  catch {
    #if any exceptions occur we assume the line is malformed
    $_ | Write-Verbose
  }
  
  if ($parts.Length -eq 7) {
    # a wellformed line should have 7 parts
    $properties = [ordered]@{
      Index = [int]$parts[0]
      Width = [int]$parts[1]
      Height = [int]$parts[2]
      Left = [int]$parts[3]
      Top = [int]$parts[4]
      Right = [int]$parts[5]
      Bottom = [int]$parts[6]
    }

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties | Write-Output
  }
}
```

## Update

@DarkDiamond, in answer to your questions:

1. I have included code comments but the outline is:

- Start mstsc.exe /l and use the process object to get the main window handle
- Use the main window handle to search (via UIAutomationClient) for the control containing the monitor definition text
- Store the monitor definition text and stop the mstsc.exe process
- Parse the monitor definition text and return a PSObject per monitor

2. I wrote the script, but I used an example of interacting with [UI Automation via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544029/2499785)
3. The solution above (using [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens) will not work in all cases as:

- The monitor indexes returned by mstsc.exe /l are not consistently aligned with DisplayName or are in continuous order (ie 0, 1, 2), on my current PC the monitor indexes are 0, 3, 4 and other users have reported the monitor indexes renumbering after reboot.
- This inconsistency in monitor indexes means that I can't create a rdp settings file for non-technical users that will consistently span the same monitors each time, so this script was developed as part of a larger PS module to dynamically generate machine specific rdp config files that work without user invention.
- My hope is that if other developers / admins have similar requirements that the snippet above will be of value.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please add some information on how this script works and where you got it from, like this the answer is not of much use as there already is a working solution.

Comment: Thx @DarkDiamond, I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I built on the great script by @djwork (thanks!), to add functionality to create a new temporary .rdp file with the desired subset of monitor indexes and launch it. Assuming that you're here to accomplish the same thing, do the following.

1. Grab the script from @djwork's answer
2. Modify line 33 to store the result into the `$monitors` variable: `$monitors = $rawText -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {`
3. Create a template .rdp file somewhere with this line in it `selectedmonitors:s:0,1`
4. Add this code to the end of the script:

```
$primaryMonitor = $monitors | ? { $_.Left -eq 0 }
$secondaryMonitor = $monitors | ? { $_.Left -gt 0 }

$replaceString = "selectedmonitors:s:{0},{1}" -f $primaryMonitor.Index, $secondaryMonitor.Index

$newRdpContent = (gc <path to template>.rdp) -replace "selectedmonitors:s:0,1", $replaceString
$tempFile = Join-Path $env:TEMP "temp.rdp"
$newRdpContent > $tempFile
start $tempFile
```

Now you can just execute this script to get the desired indexes, create a new temporary rdp file, and launch it. This example assumes that you have 3 monitors and only want to use the right-most two for RDP. You can customize it for your particular situation